# How do I allow access to the docker container on an EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a build process that looks like this:

### 1. Code Pushed to BitBucket which is picked up by BitBucker Pipelines

```
image: node:8.2.1
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Push Server to AWS Repository
        script:
          - docker login -u AWS -p $AWS_ECR_LOGIN https://$AWS_ECR_URL
          - docker build -t dev .
          - docker tag dev:latest $AWS_ECR_URL/dev:latest
          - docker push $AWS_ECR_URL/dev:latest

options:
  docker: true
```

### 2. BitBucket Pipelines Builds the Docker Image from the Dockerfile in the repo and pushes it to Amazon ECR

```
# BUILD DEV IMAGE and TEST
FROM node:8.2.1 as builder
COPY ./ /user/src/app
WORKDIR /user/src/app
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli --quiet
RUN npm install --quiet
RUN grunt build
# RUN npm test:build

# BUILD APP IMAGE
FROM node:8.2.1
COPY --from=builder /user/src/app/dist /user/src/app/
WORKDIR /user/src/app
RUN npm install -g mongodb-migrations --quiet
RUN npm install --only=prod --quiet
EXPOSE 5000
CMD npm start
```

### 3. Jenkins job watches for the new images in ECR and remotely triggers an EC2 instance to pull and restart the docker image

```
let dockerApi = new Docker({
    host: DockerIpAddress,
    port: process.env.DOCKER_PORT || 2375,
    version: 'v1.32' // required when Docker >= v1.13, https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/version-history/
});

dockerApi.createContainer({
    Image: IMAGE_NAME,
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
    Tty: true,
    Env: [`NODE_ENV=${ENV}`],
    ExposedPorts: {
        "5000/tcp": {},
    },
    HostConfig:{
        PortBindings: {
            "5000/tcp": [{
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }],
        },
    },
})
```

### Problem

Up until this point - everything is working! My docker container is running on the ec2 instance. What's not working is that I can't receive any connections. Even from ssh'd into the ec2 instance, `curl http://localhost:5000` won't work. Accessing the ec2 instance from a browser via the public ip or public host doesn't work either.

### IP Tables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             ip-172-17-0-2.ec2.internal  tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

### Sysctl

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

### Node Server in Docker Last Line of Output

```
Server running at: http://localhost:5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the Dockerfile you're using for creating the image runs a script which expose the server in 0.0.0.0 and not in localhost.

You should be opening 0.0.0.0:5000->5000 and not run in localhost!!

Hope this helps.